# Minimum of integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $S$ be the set of all integrable on $[0,1]$ such that $$\int\limits_0^1f(x)dx=\int\limits_0^1xf(x)dx+1=3.$$
Prove that $S$ is infinite and evaluate $$\min\limits_{f\in S}\int\limits_0^1f^2(x)dx.$$

Comment: To show that $S$ is infinite, just find two elements of $S$; then any linear combination is also a solution. For the minimum, the Euler-Lagrange equations with Lagrange multipliers say that $f$ should be linear, and you can determine the coefficients from the conditions; then you need to show that this is minimal in the absence of the differentiability assumptions of the Euler-Lagrange equations.

Comment: To show that the solution $f_0$ of the Euler-Lagrange equation is minimal even in absence of the differentiability assumption, write $f = f_0 + g$ and minimize $\int f(x)^2\,dx$ with respect to $g$ under the condition $\int g(x)\, dx= \int x g(x)\, dx =0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $3 = \int_0^1 f(x) \cdot \left(x +\frac{1}{3} \right) \, dx$. Let's use Cauchy–Schwarz inequality:

$$3 = \int_0^1 f(x)  \cdot \left(x +\frac{1}{3} \right) \, dx \le \sqrt{ \int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx} \sqrt{\int_0^1 \left(x +\frac{1}{3} \right)^2 dx} = \sqrt{\frac{7}{9}} \sqrt{ \int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx}$$
Hence:
$$\int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx \ge \left( \frac{9 \cdot 3}{\sqrt{7}} \right)^2 = \frac{81}{7} \approx 11.57$$

**Edit**

$$2 = \int_0^1 x f(x) \, dx \le \sqrt{ \int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx} \sqrt{\int_0^1 x^2 dx} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{ \int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx}$$
So:
$$\int_0^1 f^2(x) \, dx \ge 12 $$
And equality holds if $f(x) = 6x$

Comment: Can you give us a function for which this minimum is achieved? I think your bound is wrong. I am pretty sure that the disired minimum equals 12.

Comment: @passenger sorry, I edited my post and now bound is a bit less than 12. Equality in C-S holds if $f(x) = A(x+\frac{1}{3})$ but unfortunately there is no $A$ such that $f$ satisfies given conditions.

Comment: I found the same!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $f\in L^1([0,1])\cap L^2([0,1])$, we can take an expansion of $f$ in terms of the [shifted Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials):
$$ f(x) = a_0+\sum_{n\geq 1} c_n P_n(2x-1).\tag{1} $$
Since this set of polynomials is an orthogonal base of $L^2([0,1])$:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} P_n(2x-1) P_m(2x-1)\,dx = \frac{\delta_{m,n}}{2n+1}\tag{2} $$
and $P_0(2x-1)=1,P_1(2x-1)=2x-1$, the given constraints translate into:
$$ a_0 = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = 3, $$
$$ a_1 = 3\int_{0}^{1}(2x-1)f(x)\,dx = -9+6\int_{0}^{1}x\,f(x)\,dx =3.\tag{3}$$
So we have that any function of the form
$$ f(x) = 6x + \sum_{n\geq 2}c_n P_n(2x-1) $$
satisfies the given constraints, and:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2\,dx = a_0^2+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{c_n^2}{2n+1} \geq a_0^2+\frac{a_1^2}{3},\tag{4}$$
so the minimum for the LHS, $12$, is attained by $f(x)=6x$.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the polynomial $ax^{n+1}+bx^n$, from the equations we can derive that the coefficients satisfy two linear equations, yielding the following system:

$$\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{n+2} & \frac{1}{n+1} \\\frac{1}{n+3} & \frac{1}{n+2}\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

The determinant, $\frac{-1}{(n+1)(n+2)^2(n+3)}$, is non-zero for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so we have directly found infinite polynomial solutions. This of course, is not to say that these are *all* the solutions, so it doesn't necessarily help in evaluating the minimum (or even proving that one exists).

Answer (score 0):

A hint: For any given function $g:\ [0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ there is an $f$ of the form
$$f(x):=a + b x + g(x)$$
that fulfills the given conditions. This already proves the first part. Furthermore, any $f$ fulfilling the given conditions can be written in the above form with certain $a$, $b$ and
$$\int g(x)\ dx=0,\qquad \int_0^1 x\,g(x)\ dx=0\ .$$
Use this to solve the minimum problem.